# Unbale to read data using Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook APIs for the first time. I am trying to find my way around using Graph API Explorer.

I authorise it access my basic permission and generate an access token. Then I type me in the query box for GET method and click submit. I get the following output:

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

Debug information on token tells me that it is the right application and user. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:** Browser addon (Ghostery to be exact) was blocking Facebook Graph API. Rest of the steps were OK.

Comment: What end points are you trying to access?

Comment: It is this application, not the any I created: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: did you select an application from drop down?

Comment: I get that you are using graph explorer but what is the query that is returning the error `request failed`?

Comment: I found out a browser addon (Ghostery to be exact) was blocking Facebook Graph API. Thank everyone for your help.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error... the problem was "Ghostery" addon for Chrome.
Good Luck!!

Comment: This provides an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Ghostery' add-on disables trackers as one of its main features.

It seems to have a catch for any link associated with Facebook. If you wish to continue using the add-on without it disrupting your usage of the Graph API Explorer simply disable the single item "Facebook Social Graph" once you have selected the add-on from the top right of your browser, at the moment it is a little ghost icon just left of the customization drop down (Google Chrome).

I experienced the same issue while using the graph explorer located here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Alternatively, with the add-on enabled on your browser, visit https://apps.ghostery.com/en/apps/facebook_social_graph and ensure the option under "Want to block Facebook Social Graph?" is set to the off position.